# Finding distribution and checking independence of transformed normal variables

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, independence

$X,Y,Z$ are three independent random variables following standard normal distribution. Consider a real function $f$ such that \begin{align}f(x)&=1 , x\geq 0 \\
&= -1, x<0\\
\end{align}
Let $U,V,W$ be defined such that 
\begin{align}U&=|X| f(Y)\\
V&=|Y| f(X)\\
W&=|Z| f(X)\\
\end{align}
Then, how do I check the pairwise and mutual independence of $U,V,W$ and that these follow normal distribution.

I have no clue on how to proceed. The modulus of random variables makes it even more confusing.

Comment: What ways do you know of characterizing independence?  Which have you tried to apply?

Comment: It is $U=|X| f(Y), V=|Y| f(X), W=|Z| f(X)$.

Comment: I think you may be confusing two forms of notation, but it's hard to tell: in any event, what you wrote does not seem to characterize independence at all.  Thus, a good place to begin on this problem would be with a review of the definition.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f$ is just the $\text{sign}$ function (except at 0, but it makes no difference whether you define $f(0)$ as $-1$, $0$ or $1$ for this).

That they're individually (i.e. marginally) standard normal is obvious - you're taking a standard normal r.v., and replacing the original sign of it by a random sign ($\pm 1$), independent of the original variable.

Now consider the sign of $VW$. This should give you some clues about how to proceed.